# Creating SequenceTaggingDataset from list, not file

Tags: pytorch, torchtext

I would like to create a [SequenceTaggingDataset](https://pytorch.org/text/_modules/torchtext/datasets/sequence_tagging.html#SequenceTaggingDataset.__init__) from two lists that I have created dynamically inside my code - `train_sentences` and `train_tags`. I would want to write something like this:

```
train_data = SequenceTaggingDataset(examples=(zip(train_sentences, train_tags)))
```

However, the constructor must receive a path. And not only that - it looks from the code as though, even if I were to provide the examples, it will override those, and initialize `examples` to be an empty list.

For various reasons, I do not want to save the lists I created in a file from which the `SequenceTaggingDataset` could read. Is there any way around this, save defining my own custom class?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify source code for it (https://pytorch.org/text/_modules/torchtext/datasets/sequence_tagging.html#SequenceTaggingDataset). You can make a local copy and import as your module.

`path` is used in `__init__`. The important part is that it takes lines from file and splits it using given `separator` into list named `columns`. Then this `columns` list is being fed into another class method together with `fields` to construct `examples` list. Please read provided example [here](https://github.com/pytorch/text/blob/master/test/sequence_tagging.py) to understand `fields` (Note that `UDPOS` is called there to create `SequenceTaggingDataset`).

What you need is `columns`, which you don't need to read from file as you have all components already. You will feed it directly by simplifying class `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, columns, fields, encoding="utf-8", separator="\t", **kwargs):
    examples = []
    examples.append(data.Example.fromlist(columns, fields))
    super(SequenceTaggingDataset, self).__init__(examples, fields,
                                                 **kwargs)
```

`columns` is nested list of lists: `[[word], [UD_TAG], [PTB_TAG]]`. It means that you need to feed following into modified class:

```
train = SequenceTaggingDataset([train_sentences, train_tags], fields=...)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem straightforward at all. I saw this constructor before posting my question (as you can see by the fact that I linked to it), and it's still unclear to me. What is meant by "columns" and "fields"? I thought about trying to create a tempfile for the sake of using this ctor out of the box, and it's still unclear to me what the file should even look like. And there's no documentation to be found (as far as I can tell).

Comment: My bad, let's dive into it then. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @faerubin please have a look on modified answer. Btw you can download example of file here (https://bitbucket.org/sivareddyg/public/downloads/en-ud-v2.zip)